# The search bar, by default, places the cursor at the beginning of the text on small viewports

Tags: bug, search

When searching for something on a small viewport, selecting the search icon places the cursor at the beginning of the text in the search bar instead of the end:

[image: Screenshot of the search field with example text. Freehand red circle indicates the cursors position at the start of the text.]

This is especially prevalent when searching from the profile page or when trying to refine your current search. This is quite annoying, especially when you need to delete some, or all, of the text from the *end* of the text.

Can this be changed?

Comment: I didn't know how to add a gif, so the screenshot above shows the cursor *right after* I pressed the search icon.